# Give preference to AWS change with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this simple Cloudfront configuration:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  ...
  origin {
    domain_name = <bucket domain name>
    origin_id   = <origin id>
    origin_path = /path/1
  }
  ...
}
```

If I run `terraform apply` it creates the CloudFront distribution as it should. But after I created it, a Continuous Deployment pipeline is changing its `origin_path` from `/path/1` to `/path/<another number>`.

If I make any change on this distribution and update it with `terraform apply`, the `origin_path` goes back to `/path/1` and breaks the environment. Is there any way to avoid this?

For example:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  ...
  origin {
    domain_name = <bucket domain name>
    origin_id   = <origin id>
    origin_path = creationOnly("/path/1")
  }
  ...
}
```

And `creationOnly` would update `origin_path` only if the resource is being created.

Edit:

Thanks to Helder and Mark in the comments I figured out lifecycles would be a possible solution. Sadly, even though I used a resource on my example, the real problem involves a module.

Comment: I would recommend to keep all your changes in terraform ... but there are ways to do what you ask, look into lifecycle ignore_changes: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes

Comment: @HelderSepulveda good point, I didn't know about lifecycles, anyway they are not available to modules level yet this is an [issue on official repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27360). Sadly, even though my example use a resource, the real problem is with a module.

Comment: @Horus there is no module in your question. Why can't you use the lifecycle setting inside the `aws_cloudfront_distribution` resource?

Comment: Just made an edit @MarkB

Comment: Do you not have access to modify the code inside the module?

Comment: I do, just wanted to avoid this refactoring, but it seems there's no other option @MarkB